# What is the contraposive of this statement?

Tags: proof-writing, arithmetic

I have to prove the negation of this statement:
$$\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}{\;if\;a\;|\;b\} $$

But the fact that there is a "and" is very disturbing. I think that I am missing something because my "version" of the contraposive is obviously wrong. (take a = 3 , b = 7,  c = 4)

Comment: $\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\left( \text{ if } a\mid b+c, \text{ then either } a\mid b\text{ and } a\mid c \text{ or } a\not\mid b \text{ and } a\not\mid c\right)$, because the opposite of "$a$ divides exactly one of $b,c$" is "$a$ divides none or all of $b,c$".

Comment: Wait the contraposive of A then B isn't B then A?

Comment: No, it is "if not B, then not A".

Comment: @user314 To prove the contraposive can I negate the second part of your statement which become: $$(a\nmid b\lor a\nmid c) \wedge (a|b \lor a|c)$$ take for example $$a\nmid b \wedge a|c$$ and show that there is a contradiction. is that enough?

Comment: Let's call your original statement $P\implies Q$. Then I gave you the contraposition (an equivalent statement to yours), which is $\lnot Q\implies \lnot P$. And now you're asking whether you can assume $P$ **and not Q** and arrive at a contradiction. Yes, you can do this, but such a proof will not be called a _proof by contraposition_. It will instead be called a _proof by contradiction_. The difference is that, when you prove something by contradiction, to prove $P\implies Q$, you assume $\lnot Q$ and $P$ to arrive at a contradiction, while a contraposition requires a direct proof.

Comment: I.e., when you want to prove $P\implies Q$ by contraposition, you prove $\lnot Q\implies \lnot P$ _without assuming P_.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how I can directly prove the contraposition starting from $$a|(b+c)$$ any hints?

Comment: Please edit the LaTeX in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is equivalent to
$$\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\left( \text{ if } a\mid b+c, \text{ then either } a\mid b\text{ and } a\mid c \text{ or } a\not\mid b \text{ and } a\not\mid c\right)$$

Assume $a\mid b+c$. Then $b+c=ak, k\in\mathbb Z$. Now check two cases, which are exhaustive:

$1)$ $a\mid b$. Then $b=am, m\in\mathbb Z$ and so $b+c=am+c=ak\iff c=a(k-m)$.
Thus $\exists n\in\mathbb Z \left(c=an \right), a\neq 0$, which means $a\mid c$ by the exact [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) of divisibility.

$2)$ $a\not\mid b$. Then $b=am-r, 0<r<|a|$ and $b+c=am-r+c=ak\iff c=a(k-m)+r$.
Since $0<r<|a|$, we know that $r$ is the [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) of $c$ when $c$ is divided by $a$.
Since the remainder is not zero, we have that $a\not\mid c$.

Comment: But shouldn't 0 < r < b instead of a ? And why b = am - r and not am + r? If I understand well we can deduce from your two points that not A -> (true or false) <=> not A -> true so not A -> not B

Comment: @torr You should read the definition of [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder). As for your second question, since we know that $b$ is not divisible by $a$, we can write it was $b=am\pm r$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $0<r<|a|$. Whether you write a plus or minus sign there does not matter. E.g., $7=3\cdot 2+1, 7=3\cdot 3-2$. Whether you write $+1$ or $-2$ doesn't change the fact that it is equivalent to saying that $7$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: @torr Proving the statement right in the beginning of my answer is equivalent to proving by contraposition the statement in your main question. We assume $a\mid b+c$ and then we want to prove that either $(a\mid b)\wedge(a\mid c)$ or $(a\nmid b)\wedge(a\nmid c)$. There are exactly two cases that can then happen - either $a\mid b$ or $a\nmid b$. I then proceed to prove that if $a\mid b$, then $(a\mid b)\wedge(a\mid c)$ and if $a\nmid b$, then $(a\nmid b)\wedge(a\nmid c)$. Both these agree with what we wanted to prove, and so we are done.